# How to have Bunny process one message at a time with RabbitMQ?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

When I use Bunny, when I open a connection to a queue that has 50,000 messages using:

```
queue = channel.queue('test.queue', :durable => true)
queue.subscribe(:manual_ack => true) do ...
```

RabbitMQ moves ALL the messages from `READY` to `UNACKED` immediately, thus leaving none in `READY`.

If I try to spin up another Bunny using the same code, it now has nothing to read off `READY`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. I didn't set `pre_fetch`.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is the answer though. If you set "pre_fetch" it fixes the issue.